# Can we add Linguistics SE to the migration path list?

Tags: feature-request, migration

I know they are in beta but the following question begs to be migrated to [linguistics.se].

[Distinctive Features of English Dipthongs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/61892/distinctive-features-of-english-diphthongs).

I wonder if our passing relevant questions to other SEs would help them get out of Beta as well.

Comment: Literature.SE too. (for questions like http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63737/origin-and-meaning-of-rackers)

Comment: @Mitch: [Literature.SE is closing](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/349/literature-is-closing).

Comment: Yeah that's too bad. For them (and us...we can't forward the poetry)

Comment: Another likely example: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/370426/13804.  It seems an ok question, but it does not belong here.  Not sure how well Linguistics will take it, I have never visited there.

Comment: @cobaltduck: no need to migrate, it's been [re-asked on Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/20935/is-language-subconsciously-developed). Comments so far have said that it is rather unclear.

Answer (score 3):

[Normally migration paths are not set up until *after* the target site is out of Beta.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/add-ell-to-list-of-sites-for-off-topic-questions) I think the idea is to avoid swamping smaller sites and to give them space to determine their scope.

I don't think Linguistics SE will graduate anytime soon, though, so it's a bit of an odd situation.

Comment: The ELL path was not set up until it had graduated.

Comment: ELL's [graduation message](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2634/congratulations-english-language-learners-is-graduating) says *You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network*. It looks like the migration path was opened around Sept 22 '15 and we graduated Sept 10th. (That doesn't mean that moderators weren't migrating questions before that - it just wasn't opened up to everyone)

Comment: You're answering a question that was posed in 2012, so the claim `I don't think Linguistics SE will graduate anytime soon` has indeed been verified. AKA "Stating the bleedin' obvious" :)

Comment: And the exceptional low view count (111times in almost five years) suggests that this is not a burning issue...

Comment: @Mari-LouA no, just all of a sudden a question that should have been asked elsewhere pops up - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/401014/what-does-the-line-the-magi-brought-valuable-gifts-but-that-was-not-among-them