# Add ELL to list of sites for off topic questions

Tags: feature-request

Reviewing this question:

[What are the functions of each part of the principal parts?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106629/what-are-the-functions-of-each-part-of-the-principal-parts)

Trying to flag it to be moved to ELL. Only, ELL does not show in the list of sites. Can ELL please be added?

Comment: You mean ELL isn't in that list now? How odd.

Comment: ELL is still in beta. I'm sure it's been said here before that it must graduate before migration paths are coded (because -- in theory at least -- it might not graduate).

Comment: @AndrewLeach That makes no sense: [writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com) is in beta, and we can migrate questions there with no trouble at all.

Comment: I didn't say it made sense. I have found this though: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/3674/18696

Answer (score 1):

When a site is still in beta phase, it is not added as migration path for another site; there are exceptions to this, for example with Writers, but that site has been in beta phase 856 days (less than 2 years and a half).

While there would be some questions that are candidates for migration to ELL, ELL has been in beta phase only 59 days. When the site will be in beta phase more days, and if there are still questions that should be migrated to ELL, ELL will be added as migration path.

Comment: But ELL seems to be an exceptional case in itself where, as compared to other SE sites, noobs are supposed to be the most active of contributors, and as you may have seen or perhaps felt as well, there do arise occasions every now and then where a migration seems to be the most reasonable way for a question but only that it doesn't exist at the moment.

Comment: It's now more than a year since this answer. Questions that would be more appropriate for ELL are still fairly common (http://english.stackexchange.com/users/74633/user74633 asked several of them today). Can we bring this up for consideration again?