# A friendly reminder: ELL is not EL&U's trash can

Tags: discussion, migration, ell

We've been getting a lot of migrations to ELL lately.  That's actually fine by me – I think a lot of them are okay on ELL, even if they're not suitable for EL&U.  The two sites have different standards, and that's okay.

But we've also been getting migrations like [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83653/when-someone-wanna-talk-perfect-english):

> When someone wanna talk perfect English
>
> I wanna learn English how can I do that, can someone help me or give me good ideas
>
> Thanks

I'm sure the migration will be rejected within the hour, but it'd be better if it had never been migrated in the first place.  **Please don't migrate terrible questions!**  When questions are this bad, please use another close reason.

Comment: The approach I usually use is to ask myself whether I would be sufficiently motivated to actually *remonstrate* with another ELL user if they were to closevote as "Too Basic" (specifically, after making allowances for the fact that many non-native speakers might find it difficult to locate even quite basic information, since the Net itself is heavily skewed towards English, making *everything* a bit of a struggle). But with the example you've included above, it's just a no-brainer.

Comment: I believe the migration was a mistake. We need a close reason "This question is off-topic because it is not on-topic."

Comment: We do have close reason other.  I would like to have seen: This question is off-topic because the topic: "How to improve my English?" is expressly prohibited by the [help](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  I remember being a clueless newb.  The sticks that came with explanations did me more good than just getting beaten with the stick.

Comment: I want the ability to migrate *users* not their questions, as the answer to that question is go join ELL.

Comment: @Maxura you can find that ability in a kindly worded comment.

Comment: @CandiedOrange So what you're saying is you're okay with being beaten with the stick as long as they tell you why you're being beaten? :) On-topic, I agree that some questions have been migrated that should never have existed in the first place, but I feel that outright ostracising a user because they didn't ask a question the way we felt they should is perhaps unnecessarily harsh. Surely there's a comfortable middle-ground somewhere.

Comment: On ELU, "Questions that can be answered by a quick dictionary lookup" is not on the "do not ask about" list, while it is on ELL. ???

Comment: @user3169 Not explicitly. See [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [What's on-topic](/help/on-topic). The requirement for research is also in a closure reason, of course. However, perhaps that would be a good addition to the "Don't ask" list.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Understood, but "research" is a broad term, and especially for the learner a clear "check your dictionary first" would be appropriate.

Comment: @JohnClifford, whoa, who is being ostracized? Closing a question without migrating is not supposed to be seen as equivalent to ostracizing the person who asked it.

Comment: Just wondering - now that ELL has established its identity and moved out of Beta, is it time to stop the systematic migration of questions from ELU to ELL?

Comment: @Lawrence Migrations are supposed to be limited *before* graduation (so the site has a chance to form its own identity rather than being overwhelmed with higher traffic from another site), not after.

Comment: So then is it time for someone to go out to Area 51 and try to launch "Infelicitous Inquiries SE" as an involuntary migratory destination for everyone's dross?

Comment: This query might help the discussion - it's migrations that were rejected on ELL: http://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/411705/rejected-migrations#resultSets (Click on the column header to sort by date). What I'd like to do is also write/find a query on migrated questions that were upvoted (say more than twice) to get a list of questions that were welcomed.

Comment: @ColleenV How did you find that coding tool? It's like an SE [easter egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_%28media%29)! :)

Comment: @sumelic I had the same reaction at first to JohnClifford's use of "ostracising", but then I figured it must be a response to Mazura's comment above it about "migrating users".

Comment: @Rob_Ster Exactly. I cant believe the arguements in the comments below. By their logic we should migrate all closed questions to Stack Overflow, its their job to close them - not our fault for migrating.

Comment: "Migrate the user," was poorly said. What I meant was when a question gets migrated, an account is created for the user at the appropriate site. Ostracize? no. More like: *'We've taken the liberty of creating you an account at, and have moved your question to...'*

Comment: Sorry, not *is*: 'should be'.

Comment: @Mazura No, no account is created, if the OP doesn't go to the site where the question was migrated, and decides to create an account. What is automatic is assigning the questions asked by that user to that user.

Comment: Has the question been featured for long enough?

Comment: Well, allow me to say congratulations on being the most upvoted question in the history of EL&U meta. And I detected not the slightest hint of animosity, I was more peeved about the strain of comments, than your actual request.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It makes me happy that it got so many upvotes.  I take it as a sign that the EL&U folks really do care about ELL :-)

Answer (score 14):

Everyone's banging on about that one bad question that was migrated.

> Someone lets their dog crap in my yard and I go out and scoop it. Now I can toss it in the garbage, or I can go leave it on my neighbor's lawn, because he has to clean up after the dog walkers sometimes too. It seems stupid to try justify dropping that crap on my neighbor's yard because if the dog had just walked a couple more feet it would have been in his yard. I've already done the work to clean it up, why would I ask my neighbor to do it too? [Colleen](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7784/a-friendly-reminder-ell-is-not-elus-trash-can/7876?noredirect=1#comment32477_7876)

> Roaring your arguments are ridiculous. I'm being blunt here, since the complex reasoning is explained above clearly already. The question was trash. ELU users used ELL as a trash can. ELL doesn't appreciate being treated as a trash can. [Viizionary](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7784/a-friendly-reminder-ell-is-not-elus-trash-can/7876?noredirect=1#comment32488_7876)

and ...

> @Mari-LouA It seems simple. Migration is a process for users who have a strong understanding that the question would be a good fit for the site they're migrating it to. Not only was the question an obviously terrible question for the site, the question was an obviously terrible question for any SE site. ...[Viizionary](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7784/a-friendly-reminder-ell-is-not-elus-trash-can/7876?noredirect=1#comment32554_7876)

the crap analogy continues....

> Wow, so much fuss over something so obvious. Don't send us your crap, okay? The end
>    [IͶΔ](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7784/a-friendly-reminder-ell-is-not-elus-trash-can/7876?noredirect=1#comment32584_7876)

In case it needed reminding, which judging by the stream of comments under Roaring Fish's answer it appears necessary, the number of users who voted to migrate the question: [When someone wanna talk perfect English](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83653/when-someone-wanna-talk-perfect-english), were exactly three. Three users out of the hundreds of users who have earned the ‘privilege’ to close questions through democratic decision. **Only three users voted to migrate it**, not five. I was the 5th user to cast their vote to close that question. It needed to be closed. It was a very, very poor fit for a Q&A website, but three other users believed that ELL could make something from it.

However, the question was clearly off-topic for both English sites, that is not under discussion, mistakes happen and we can all benefit from understanding how to avoid repeating them in the future, but from here to claiming that EL&U dumps their “crap” on ELL — is jingoistic war warmongering at its worst.

Comment: Since so much is being made of that particular example, it may be worth noting that four of the five close voters on that question at ELL are high-rep users at EL&U—snailboat being the lowest-rep voter at EL&U among those four. So at least in that instance, most of the people doing the cleanup work for ELL participate at both sites.

Comment: ...That circumstance leads me to wonder whether the solution to bad migration requests might be to restrict the vote-to-migrate privilege to people who have vote-to-close privileges at both sites. I have sometimes suggested in comments that a poster consider asking a seemingly elementary question at ELL, but I've never voted to migrate a question to ELL because I feel insufficiently attuned to that site's standards and interests to make good calls about what particular questions are welcome there. Worthless crap or enriching manure? It's a question for the lawn's owners to decide, I think.

Comment: @SvenYargs it's a bit of a no-brainer closing that question, you don't need much rep to see that it was simply an inappropriate question for a Q&A format. Perhaps some users thought ELL was the best place to help that particular user. That maybe the more experienced members could have dedicated more time to that learner and provided greater guidance. Who knows.

Comment: That question belongs on Meta.SE. There it would get (closed as a [dupe?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239323/where-should-i-ask-a-question-about-teaching-english-as-a-2nd-language) ) three suggestions, to be completed in order: Join ELL. Join ELU. Join Writers.SE. -Profit. (the migrated post is locked, so I'll just leave this right here)

Comment: `jingoistic war warmongering at it's worst` is a little dramatic for a legitimate complaint about the quality of the questions that are getting migrated. We have plenty of overlap in our communities, so there aren't even 'sides'. I posted to provide some feedback to this community about bad/weird migrations, not just to bitch about one question. Maybe I shouldn't have agreed so readily to closing my discussion post as a duplicate of this one. Because so few people can migrate a question it's important to talk openly about what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @ColleenV  My melodramatic turn of phrase was an attempt to illustrate how melodramatic the tone of "legitimate complaints" were, saying that users on EL&U send crap, or newcomers poop on EL&U and ELL is kind of an exaggeration, isn't it?

Comment: Right, because tit-for-tat is the most mature and constructive way to handle things. You can get all defensive and pretend like we're attacking EL&U for no reason and make excuses instead of hearing what we're trying to tell you and work with us to make things better for both sites. I like and respect a lot of folks in both communities, so this isn't about ELL vs EL&U. All I'm asking is for folks to set the bar higher for the quality of questions they vote to migrate. I don't speak for all of ELL and I'm not talking to all of EL&U, just the folks that migrate crap questions.

Comment: @ColleenV   And I was pointing out that the folks who migrate the crap questions are a minuscule number,  it's worthwhile remembering that only  three votes are necessary to migrate a question, so perhaps a more constructive suggestion would be to demand that  five votes are needed for migrating, otherwise the question is put on hold and left to the mods' discretion. I believe they are probably the  best to judge whether a question remains on EL&U or not.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Last I checked it takes four migration votes, not just three.

Comment: @tchrist I distinctly recall 3 CV for migration, and 1 for a separate reason, I added my CV as being  too broad, and the question immediately migrated.

Comment: @tchrist Maybe it takes four migration votes on Stack Overflow, but three elsewhere?  [Jeff Atwood posted about raising the requirement to 4/5 back in 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97700/215040), but he said "This is also specific to Stack Overflow only at the moment".  I don't see any more recent posts suggesting the change has been rolled out to other sites.

Answer (score -6):

Maybe the problem is that questions get migrated at all?

If that option is there, then I don't see anything unreasonable in expecting the ELL community to sort out which ones to close. Surely that is more reasonable than expecting the ELU community to make those decisions for ELL.

If the sheer volume of migrated questions is becoming a problem, I think it would be better just to take the option away, or change it to something more akin to a resubmission option presented to the poster: "your question is not right for ELU. Perhaps you would like join our other site here (ELL link)"

**Edit**

Looking at the history of discussion about migrations to ELL, we see [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/can-we-add-english-language-learners-to-the-belongs-on-another-se-site-list?rq=1) (repeated [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7128/should-we-have-a-migration-path-to-ell?rq=1)) that even when ELL was in beta and migrations were handled by moderators, ELL still rejected one out of six of them. This kills the argument that 'folks with enough rep to migrate should know what fits and what doesn't.'

Both of those threads also have warnings that opening a migration channel could lead to problems of ELL accusing ELU of sending crap. Those predictions have come true. I can't really think of a better argument for closing the migration channel.

Comment: I believe that just like we wouldn't migrate a spammy or abusive or blatantly off-topic post on the grounds that "it's not our place to moderate ELL, they can close if they want", there are questions which are *bad*, uniformly across SE, which should just be closed.

Comment: I would argue that by dumping an obviously bad question on ELL you are expecting us to take on some of ELU's moderation duties. I don't think anyone is asking ELU to screen for duplicates or only migrate questions that have no chance of being closed. Surely most folks with enough rep to vote to migrate can discern the difference between questions that fit in the SE system and those that don't.

Comment: Also, if the migration path were shut down today, it wouldn't be ELL that suffers. It is to ELU'S benefit to direct users to the site where they can get the best answers to their question. If their question is welcomed the next one along those lines may get asked elsewhere first. It's not good for anyone for a question to get bounced back and forth. It just generates bad will and meta complaint threads.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan ~ questions that are *bad* do get closed. The ones that get kicked to ELL are the 'too easy' ones, which the ELU community can close if they don't like them.

Comment: @ColleenV ~ the problem isn't whether a question fits in with the SE system. Those that don't fit do get closed, arguably too many of them, and it is very misleading to pretend that ELU is sending those to ELL. We don't. What snailboat is complaining about is questions that don't fit the ELL idea of suitable questions, and what I am saying is that ELL cannot expect ELU to filter those for them. ELL has to do that itself, or simply cut the migration link. ELU got along without that before, so I don't think anyone would suffer from cutting it. We would just close instead of migrating.

Comment: You are suggesting that the question quoted in the post by snailboat, which was in fact migrated, is a question that fits the SE system?

Comment: I would have flagged it as too broad, but you are completely missing the point here. This is a simple matter of who decides which questions are right for ELL.  Answer a couple of questions: if that question had gone directly into ELL, what would you have done with? And what did you actually do with it?  If those two questions have the same answer, then you have no grounds to be complaining at ELU, and by doing so you are expecting ELU to moderate for ELL. That being the case, I would cut the migration link to save having complaining threads like this repeating over and over again.

Comment: Someone lets their dog crap in my yard and I go out and scoop it. Now I can toss it in the garbage, or I can go leave it on my neighbor's lawn, because he has to clean up after the dog walkers sometimes too. It seems stupid to try justify dropping that crap on my neighbor's yard because if the dog had just walked a couple more feet it would have been in his yard. I've already done the work to clean it up, why would I ask my neighbor to do it too? Also, I have "grounds" to discuss issues that face any of the communities on SE that I am a member of on their meta sites.

Comment: To make your scenario relevant, you need to add the details that your neighbours exists for people to throw dog poop on, has signs inviting people to throw poop on, you have an arrangement with the neighbour to throw dog poop on it, and your neighbour is complaining that some of the dog poop you throw is the wrong colour. Details make a difference.

Comment: You are still missing the point, or maybe deliberatel avoiding it as you refused to answer my questions illustrating it. To put it as simply as I can, if ELL wants posts migrated from ELU, then ELL has to accept that some of those migrated will not be acceptable to the ELL community and the ELL community will have to take on the role of deciding which ones to close, exactly as they would if the questions were posted directly. If ELL doesn't want them, then cut the link. What ELL shouldn't do is open threads like this, complaining that ELU is not choosing *for ELL* which questions to close.

Comment: Roaring your arguments are ridiculous. I'm being blunt here, since the complex reasoning is explained above clearly already. The question was trash. ELU users used ELL as a trash can. ELL doesn't appreciate being treated as a trash can. Enough said.

Comment: @Viziionary~ like @ColleenV, you are completely missing the point. Whether the OP question is good or bad is irrelevant. The issue is who makes the decision of what questions are acceptable on ELL. You seem to think ELU should make that choice; I say ELL should decide what questions to close in ELL.  You say this is ridiculous but offer no arguments against it, and completely miss the point. As you say... enough said.

Comment: @Viziionary the questions on ELL are pretty dire in the first place, with or without EL&U's scraps. I'd be interested to know what the percentage of closed questions has been since ELL became a fully fledged site. Has it fallen, risen, remained stable? The number of visits ELL questions attract is also pitifully low, there's a reason for this: LQQ. It's the same affliction across the board. Roaring Fish is saying (I think) that it should be ELL who decide which questions should be closed. Aren't you? Problem is, even half decent questions tend to stay on EL&U, no one wants to let go of those.

Comment: @Mari-LouA~ you think correctly. The way I see it, if OP had posted in ELL, they would just close it. He posted it in ELU, who migrated it. ELL can close it, exactly as if it were posted directly. It is the same sequence - I see no problem there!  What I do see as a problem is ELL starting meta threads like this grumbling that ELU are not doing the closing on behalf of ELL. As long as migrations continue, the grumbling will continue, which is why I suggest cutting it and replacing it with a link. Then the OP can go directly to ELL, who can respond as they like leaving ELU safely out of it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It seems simple. Migration is a process for users who have a strong understanding that the question would be a good fit for the site they're migrating it to. Not only was the question an obviously terrible question for the site, the question was an obviously terrible question for any SE site. By this guy's logic, why not just migrate every off topic question to every SE site? Its their job to close questions why shouldnt we migrate all of our closed questions to Stack Overflow? They would close the bad question anyway....

Comment: When you make a bad migration you waste time for the other site's moderators who now have to reject your terrible migration request. Dont migrate things unless you understand the format of the Stack Exchange network and the site you're migrating the question to.

Comment: @Viziionary We do not migrate questions that are general reference. We do not migrate questions that are opinion based. We migrate questions that are too simple for ELU, and as migration is not decided by a single individual, a group of people agree to migrate it. Once it arrives in ELL, it is up to you to do what you want to do with it. The answer, as I keep saying, is to stop migrating, then ELL has nothing to complain about. We close them if they come here, and you will have to close them youselves if they go there. End of problem.

Comment: @Viziionary~thinking downvotes speak anything at all is a logical fallacy, and on a personal level I am actually quite pleased about them. What does speak is that you point to those instead of presenting a good reason why ELU should moderate for ELL, or why the migration should not be cut and ELL left to stand on their own.

Comment: By your logic we should migrate all of our closed questions to Stack Overflow. Its their job to close them if they want to, not ours.

Comment: Wow, so much fuss over something so obvious. Don't send us your crap, okay? The end

Comment: @IͶΔ ~ thanks for agreeing with me. It is indeed obvious that we should simply take away the migrate option and stop sending ELL crap. The odd thing is that ELL complain about the posts we migrate, but still complain when I suggest that we stop migrating posts.

Comment: Going back to the dog poop analogy: A letter that is meant for my neighbour came to me instead, by mistake. I send it over to him. Acceptable. Dog poop showed up on my yard; its meant neither for me nor for him, and i know that. He has no interest in dog poop, he even has fine print on his mail box saying please don't leave dog poop on my yard. Its (supposed to be) common knowledge that people don't like dog poop. I still send it over to him. NOT acceptable. Of course, he can still make the call to throw it away or not. But you see why it was wrong of me to dump it on him in the first place..

Comment: And of course... Just because your neighbour doesn't want you sending over dog poop, please don't stop sending over his mail that got delivered to you by mistake. And he trusts you to know the difference. I rest my case.

Comment: A poor analogy. Lets make it more accurate. I get mail. It is not addressed. Some of it interests me so I keep it. Some of it is junk-mail so I throw it. Some of it might interest you, so I pass it to you. After all, you can always throw it yourself if you don't find it interesting. As I am not a mind reader some of the stuff is not interesting which is to be expected, but instead of just putting in the bin you start waving it around, stamping your feet, and complaining about it. I suggest that instead of passing it to you I just return it to the sender. You start complaining about that too...

Comment: @IͶΔ the "crap" is on both sites, good or half-decent questions on EL&U will remain here because users want to answer them. Some LQQs can be made on topic with a bit of effort, and be perfectly suitable for ELL, but I rarely see Ellers doing that, the atrocious spelling and grammar errors that are left intact seem to suggest that 1. ELL users are unaware of such simple basic errors  2. They can't be bothered to edit the posts into shape or 3. the few users who really care are just swamped, and have given up.

Comment: @Mari that's another issue. Let's not forget that what prompted this question was something that was off-topic in all language sites. How much polishing can be done to such questions?

Comment: @IͶΔ you're all going about that one particular question, the same question which I immediately voted as being off topic, and was closed in a matter of minutes. Mistakes happen, get over it. My point about LQQs is very relevant, one way to polish them is by correcting the most basic grammatical errors without affecting the actual question. This also applies to the **answers**.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - or 4. That the ELL community feels that it's important to leave such errors intact, so that the asker's proficiency levels are kept plain, and that the question doesn't make the OP appear more advanced than reality would indicate. See StoneyB's Point #2 in his [answer to this ELL meta question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/why-dont-people-point-out-secondary-question-language-issues-within-their-answe/1061#1061).

Comment: I don't think it's a problem if 9 out of every 10 questions migrated gets closed, if the questions we're closing aren't obviously a waste of everyone's time. I fully expect to have to close a ton of duplicates that get migrated, because the person posting searched EL&U and not ELL before posted (yeah, I know that doesn't really happen that often, but let's pretend). We can't pull a SCOTUS and say "I can't define it, but I know it when I see it?" and err on the side of not migrating obviously bad questions?

Comment: @ColleenV ~ bad questions *in your opinion*. You are expecting everybody in ELU to have exactly the same opinions as you. Can you show me an example of that ever happening in the real world? It doesn't, because humans are not like that. If ELL is going to take the road of complaining that ELU users don't have the opinions as you then the choice is endless threads like this, or close the migration channel and replace with a link. I think the latter is better option than endless complaining from ELL.

Comment: You know for folks that go on and on about how high your standards are, y'all seem to have a lot of trouble calling a duck a duck. Alright, everything is subjective and I'm sure we'll never agree that "Learn me to speakgood English" is a bad question.

Comment: If we are discussing that single question, you are being petty. If we are discussing a trend of bad ( in your opinion...) questions then that question is irrelevant.

Comment: @J.R.: I think your comment at the very least overstates (if not actually *misleads*) regarding a "site consensus" on ELL to *leave errors intact, so that the asker's proficiency levels are kept plain*. There's considerable support for my suggestion that edits are good [*if they're correcting obvious grammatical errors that wouldn't be made by a competent native speaker*](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/93/126). Much the same point is made by Robert Cartaino♦ on that same page (*also* substantially endorsed). The only answer taking a different stance there has 3 downvotes and no upvotes.

Comment: @Fumble - I didn't mean to mislead anyone. The comment I replied to reads, "_atrocious spelling and grammar errors that are left intact seem to suggest that 1. ELL users are unaware of such simple basic errors 2. They can't be bothered to edit the posts into shape or 3. the few users who really care are just swamped, and have given up_." That paints a pretty bleak picture of ELL. I thought it was worth mentioning that at least some errors might be left alone on purpose, so maybe things aren't as bad as that comment might indicate. I understand that some routine housekeeping does get done.

Comment: @J.R.: My bad. I didn't really register the significance of **or 4** at the start of your comment (implying *This is a **fourth possible reason** for retaining low-quality question text*). But the fact that I *did* get it somewhat wrong does suggest the comment was potentially misleading (either that, or I have seriously limited reading comprehension skills! :) But even if *the ELL community feels that...* only references a *possible* reason, I think it's a bit of an overstatement (better might have been something like ***another possible reason is some potential ELL editors feel that...***)

Answer (score -6):

I think it should be, but you'd have to read my comments above to understand *how* and *why*.

I think it's pretty easy to identify *users*, who *belong*,* on ELL.

But this question, and the general animosity about migrating to ELL, prevents me from even trying. If that was your goal, you've succeeded. (*friendly* indeed, in my mind that's a different "f" word, just cleverly worded.)

** users whose own self interest, as well as the interest of SE at large, would be better served there

How can we expect users with a poor grasp of English to be instantly good SE'ers *on sites where the text is in English*? How does ELL deal with questions like that? Are they just complaining because they already have to deal with plenty of them, themselves? And basically have no outlet for, "You're beyond any help (*that would be on-topic for this site*), try [this site.]" like ELU does?

*Shouldn't* it be ELL's job to teach people English *and* how to SE at the same time?

---

IMO, if you don't want crap questions migrated, make a feature request at ELU for an automatic "user creation script" for *user* (migration) / creation (or some such route for what I'm intending). Then you can have them all to yourselves from the get-go. However, this may be difficult to implement without SE itself violating the Be Nice policy.

Having to "kindly word" *yo, you need to go learn how to english* is not my cup of tea. It does however, pain me to admit that I've given up on y'all (users who need help). SE exists to answer people's questions, not to make life easier for moderators or whatever.

---

The example question is actually a [dupe of a Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255813/learners-of-english-se-site) (cross-site duping is a battle for another day). This one is even better, because it's written in the broken English someone would use to ask it. And it (the link) has but one sole answer that might as well have a full stop after: Go join ELL.

**I'll take any DVs as, "That user migration thing would be even worse." Please note if otherwise** and BTW, you can leave the "kid gloves" at the door. Mine came off when the OP *fudged* the F word. Or don't (explain yourself), the numbers on my first comment and the one below it, tell us that about 1/3 of the users who read it agree (that there should be a way to migrate users, which also tells us that it's unlikely to be *status: completed*). So, if this ends up with half as many ups as downs, we won't make any ground here unless you explain why.

Comment: I'm honestly quite shocked that you think I "*fudged* the F word".

Comment: @snailboat - Intended or not, that's how I've come to read it. *Stop F-ing using ELL as ELU's trash can. Thank you.*

Comment: Rather than migrating a bad question, you can just leave a comment saying something like "If you are a English language learner, the following site may be more appropriate for your questions: http://ell.stackexchange.com But this particular question is not a good fit at either site for so-and-so reasons." It would be nice to have an automatic way to do this, but that's the case for many other types of comments. I think some users have written scripts that can do this. And you can also just copy-paste if you have a good place to store these messages.

Comment: Here's a [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/320725/there-is-a-sentence-i-cant-fully-understand-check-these-things-please) that currently, four people think should be migrated to ELL. I disagree; their command (the OP) of the English language is good enough to operate at ELU. The only problem it had was (almost) failing to avoid a Proofreading VTC. Proofreading is not summarily off-topic. But lacking sufficient "command" is grounds for account-migration IMO. The context of the question has nothing to do with it. The goal is to help the user now and users later.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder how many ELL questions are closed for being unclear, and forever will be.